# form Class not Found in Laravel

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel and following the ACL Instructions of the Laravel 4 Cookbook.

[github tutorial  4 code](https://github.com/formativ/tutorial-laravel-4-acl)

[ACL tutorial](https://medium.com/laravel-4/laravel-4-acl-a7f2fa1f9791)

I made a forms directory in app/ and put the 2 ****Form.php files in there. Now I have created a GroupController and a addAction (just like in the example). But when i Call the add Route: localhost:8000/group/add I got this error:

> Class 'GroupForm' not found

line 7 in GroupController`$form = new GroupForm();`

I did composer dump-autoload.

But still get the error message.

Any help?

Composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable"
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the location of your ***Form.php to your composer autoload. It should work after that.

Comment: posted my composer.json file, but must i list my GroupForm in there?

Comment: added "app/forms", to my composer.json file. It works now. Thx for your hint

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, first add the "app/forms" autoload in composer.json

then run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 2):

I just want to mention that if you're using **Laravel 5** Html and Form have been removed because they are not core components.

1. Add requirement for Illuminate Html in composer.json

   `"illuminate/html": "~5.0"`
2. Update composer

   `update composer`
3. In config/app.php

   a. Add the service provider to the providers array:

   `'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider'`

   b. Add these two lines in the aliases array:

   `'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
    'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'`